# How to set a control resource dictionary in a Style in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight

I have a UI in Silverlight with some borders, and with a TextBlock inside that borders. There will be other TextBlocks outside borders.

```
<Border>
    <TextBlock>This text should be centered</TextBlock>
</Border>

<Border>
    <TextBlock>This one too</TextBlock>
</Border>

<TextBlock>this one shouldn't</TextBlock>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to format all TextBlock's inside a Border, without having to set the style in every TextBlock. If it was CSS , it will be something like that : `.border .textBlock { (...) }`

I know i can set a style inside the scope of a border:

```
<Border>
    <Border.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>    
        </Style>
    </Border.Resources>
    <TextBlock>Centered Text</TextBlock>
</Border>
```

But I would still need to set this to every border in my page. So now i presente the question, can i set  in a style, in order to set it one time to affect all Borders? I tried the code bellow, but it didn't work. It didn't give me any errors, but it didn't affect the TextBlock formatting either.

```
<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="Resources">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />  
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

This works in WPF. In Silverlight I am afraid you cannot do this though.

Comment: Didn't work in silverlight, as you said, I get the message "The member "Resources" is not recognized or is not accessible."

Comment: In Silverlight the answer to your question is simply no as I stated in the answer. What you are trying to do is not supported.